# The factorial of an inputted number in Flowgorithm

Tags: computer-science, factorial, flowgorithm

So, we were given this assignment in our CS class that instructed us to make a flowchart in Flowgorithm that computes and displays the factorial of an inputted number (as seen in the Google Classroom screenshot).

[Google Classroom screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTJD2.png), [Given Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34oz8.png), [Given Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3PuW.png), [Given Picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYYQu.png).

I have already made 2 programs that can output a factorial of the number. One that simply outputs, and another one where you can input how much of a gap there is from one factor to another.

[Program 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7p3L.png), [Program 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4frTk.png).

The problem with those programs, though, is that they can not replicate the outputs seen in the pictures. They also do not use the formula given, as that formula only properly calculates factorials until 4.

So, is there any way to:

1. Display all numbers needed for the factorial in the output as seen in the given pictures;
2. and Use the formula given without changing it.

Comment: Hi, welcome ! Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also relevant for this: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). Don't use StackOverflow as a code delivery service - please add the code you attempted a solution with and we can certainly help debug.